# Why is my neighbor's bathroom plumbing connected to mine?

Tags: bathroom

Why would 2 different bathroom units belonging to 2 separate occupants be connected?  I understand that all floors are connected vertically, but what is the reason for a neighbor's bathroom to be horizontally connected to mine?

I do not understand why my bathroom plumbing (sink, tub, toilet) is connected to my next door neighbor in a large residential. I have always understood the vertical connection of all occupants--straight up and down connecting to the building water tank and boiler. Why in the world is there a need to be connected to the neighbor so that when anyone of us have problems the other does too. This is a horizontal connection that does not seemed to make sense, especially for an older building (1950's or so)?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "connected" -- are you saying there's a door between them? Or did you mean they share the same wiring and/or plumbing? In any case, no one here can answer that, ask your building engineer. Possibly a single large dwelling was separated into 2 separate dwellings, but they were not fully separated. Whether or not what you're seeing is legal will depend on where the building is located and when it was built and/or when construction was last done on the bathrooms.

Comment: To tie into the vertical stacks, it's common for multiple units to have branch lines to shared verticals.

Comment: In multi-unit construction, one would generally expect to find bathrooms, kitchens and laundry rooms built back-to-back. That is to reduce the complexity of plumbing runs in the building, and often to keep plumbing lines away from the exterior of the building to reduce worries of water lines freezing.

Comment: Harper your comment is a good answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

### This is normal practice for many multifamily buildings

It's quite normal for apartments and hotel rooms to be built with their wet spaces (bathrooms and kitchens) "back to back" across a common "wet wall".  This allows a pair of units on each floor to share the same vertical plumbing stack, which reduces the amount of plumbing needed compared to giving each "stack" of units its own plumbing stack.